# how to do vb.net replace on a byte array

Tags: vb.net

I have a byte array of data.  How can I find and replacement a part of the byte array with replacement data?

dim foo as byte
foo = MY DATA

If foo was a string, then I would do:
foo = replace( foo, target, replacement )

But foo is a byte array.  How can I replace?

Comment: A `Byte` array is like any other array.  There is no specific method for finding a sequence of elements and replacing them.  You have to write your own code.  Find an appropriate pattern-matching algorithm and implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, here is an implementation:

```
<TestMethod()>
Public Sub Test_ArrayReplace()
    AssertEqualArray({1, 4}, ArrayReplace({1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {4}))
    AssertEqualArray({1, 4, 5}, ArrayReplace({1, 2, 3, 5}, {2, 3}, {4}))
    AssertEqualArray({1, 4, 2}, ArrayReplace({1, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3}, {4}))
    AssertEqualArray({1, 4, 5, 2}, ArrayReplace({1, 2, 3, 2}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}))
    AssertEqualArray({1, 2, 3, 8, 9}, ArrayReplace({1, 2, 3, 8, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4}, {9}))

    AssertEqualArray({1, 68, 69, 70, 255}, ArrayReplace({1, 65, 66, 67, 255}, "ABC", "DEF", Encoding.ASCII))
End Sub

Private Sub AssertEqualArray(expected() As Byte, actual() As Byte)
    Assert.IsNotNull(expected, "expected")
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual, "actual")
    Assert.AreEqual(expected.Length, actual.Length, "length")
    For index = 0 To actual.Length - 1
        Assert.AreEqual(expected(index), actual(index), String.Format("index: {0}", index))
    Next
End Sub

Public Function ArrayReplace(data() As Byte, find As String, replacement As String, enc As Encoding) As Byte()
    Return ArrayReplace(data, enc.GetBytes(find), enc.GetBytes(replacement))
End Function

Public Function ArrayReplace(data() As Byte, find() As Byte, replacement() As Byte) As Byte()
    Dim matchStart As Integer = -1
    Dim matchLength As Integer = 0

    Using mem = New IO.MemoryStream
        For index = 0 To data.Length - 1
            If data(index) = find(matchLength) Then
                If matchLength = 0 Then matchStart = index
                matchLength += 1
                If matchLength = find.Length Then
                    mem.Write(replacement, 0, replacement.Length)
                    matchLength = 0
                End If
            Else
                If matchLength > 0 Then
                    mem.Write(data, matchStart, matchLength)
                    matchLength = 0
                End If
                mem.WriteByte(data(index))
            End If
        Next

        If matchLength > 0 Then
            mem.Write(data, data.Length - matchLength, matchLength)
        End If

        Dim retVal(mem.Length - 1) As Byte
        mem.Position = 0
        mem.Read(retVal, 0, retVal.Length)
        Return retVal
    End Using
End Function
```

The implementation is surely not perfect and might even be buggy.

Keep in mind that in order to convert a `String` into an ByteArray you **have** to know the `Encoding` of the `String`.
You can call it this way:

```
foo = ArrayReplace(foo, "find", "replace", Encoding.UTF8)
```